# SQL best match based on frequency of word matches

Tags: sql, substring, rank

I have this sql code but it's not working.

It should be pulling the best match based on frequency of full word matches, but its pulling the wrong row.  Order of words should not matter.

For example say @filter = "flower Doe"

and i have MYDBTitle like this:

```
1: hello Doe John flower
2: wildflower test
```

It selected the second row event though flower is not a separate word and the first row has two matches.

Is there a better way to do this without XML? Maybe with Substring,Charindex and LEN?

```
BEGIN
  SET @Split = ' '
  SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@filter,@Split,'</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')

  ;with cte1 as (
   SELECT SearchItems = '%'+T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')+'%'
   FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
  )
  SELECT Top 1  MYDB.* 
  FROM MYDB WITH(NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN cte1 on MYDB.MYDBTitle like SearchItems
  AND MYDB.Category IS NOT NULL
END
```

I have another attempt here that is not working without XML

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2d69/1

Comment: WHERE (pkbTitle LIKE '%' + @filter + '%') , this line is looking for row contains orange is green while you should split each word by space and then check row contains each , this is happening in row...moreover you can try endeca and elasticsearch ...if you are not strict with relation databse

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anybody who looked at this.  It was solved by implementing fulltext search.